# What is this "power enumerator" in Scythe?

Tags: scythe

In the top right corner of Scythe gameboard is this "power enumerator".
[image: Cut of Scythe gameboard]

However, I fail to find any information related to this "enumerator" in guide and automata guide as well.
Do you have any idea what is it for?

*Note: This is from the standard "single" side, not the half-cut, extensible side.*

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is the number of each denomination of power card in the deck. This is the same as the table in the [rules](https://stonemaiergames.com/games/scythe/rules-and-print-play/) on page 22.